# An unhandled exception occurred: Port 4200 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port

Tags: html, css, angular, localhost, port

[I tried to access localhost:4200 on my browser for my project. And the compile error message showed up each time I opened localhost4200. It says port 4200 is already in use. I tried online method like Ctrl+C but it doesn't work and have the error message shows up again. Could you help me with this problem? Thanks! The first screenshot is what my browser web page looks like when I go to localhost 4200.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoPF4.png)

[This is what showed me in the terminal window after I run npm start. I could not run ng serve for some reasons. But the npm start works fine for me before.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWfyw.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can kill the port with:

```
kill $(lsof -ti:4200)
```

And then run `ng serve` again.

Although you have two different problems that are most likely not connected. The error you're seeing in the browser is due to a code error which we'd need more information to help you fix.

Answer (score 0):

This was in my archive. How to kill all node processes on a windows machine? `taskkill /F /IM node.exe`

Here is another way to do it.

`killall node`

Answer (score 0):

if you're using windows ,then you can use netstat -ano|findstr 4200 to get the pid
then you can use taskkill /f /t /im yourpid  to close 4200 port,then start it again .hope it could help you

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the task that is running on 4200 or just use ng serve --port 4201